# Extracting files from a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know of a query, script or way of how I can extract actual files, example a jpeg, msg, or xls file, etc. from a database?  Basically, the files are not saved on a physical drive.  They are stored within the database.  How can I export/extract them from the database?

Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Using which programming language?  (Or, which programming languages do you know?)

Comment: Also, how are they stored in the database?

Comment: And which DB ? MySQL, MS-SQL, Oracle...

Comment: and which programming language(s) do you know?  This being a programming site n' all?

Answer (score 0):

Does your SQL server have Binary Large OBjects (BLOBs) types? BLOBs were made so that you could store and extract files such as these.

Take a look at this [Blob description](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html). You can use the InputStream to read your Excel file into [Apache POI-HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html), for instance.